# How to render JSON response of Django autocomplete_light when I have UI in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django, autocomplete

**Scenario** : I have AngularJS on frontend and Django on backend. I have used `watson` for searching the products in Database. I am trying to implement *autocomplete_light* for the "search" (*input type="text"*).

```
$('#searchText').yourlabsAutocomplete({
    url: '{% url "get_search_results" %}', // this is where watson is getting used
    choiceSelector: 'a',
    minimumCharacters: 4,

}).input.bind('selectChoice', function(e, choice, autocomplete) {
    window.location.href = choice.attr('href');
});
```

**Expected behaviour**: The above code works fine and shows `product_json` as I type in search textfield but I want it in a perfectly rendered html  format. I wonder how can I use AngularJS here to render  this JSON and provide `href` as per the selection.

I found below link as a doc of ***autocomplete.js***

http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/stable-2.x.x/_static/autocomplete.html

Comment: It seems that you mix jQuery with Angular. Which is not a good practice (It won't get in the Angular digest cycle). If I understand it correctly you could use the angular UI typeahead: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ (at the bottom)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a custom search script , you can use Angular to call it and create custom TextAhead